Update child SID to put user on hold ends the parent SID call automatically
I am trying to facilitate putting users on hold for both outbound and inbound calls. It is working perfectly for inbound calls, but when I update the users child SID for outbound calls my side of the call immediately ends. I want to be able to stay in an active call by myself and eventually transfer the user back in. Im currently just using update twiml for these transfers. Is there any way to make this work without using conference? Thank you
I tried to use enqueue instead of say and play (loop) but that just gives me an error and also ends the call
